# Term frequency in solrj

Tags: solrj

I using SOLRJ to find term frequency for each term in a field, I wrote this code but it is not working:

```
public static SolrRequest req;
public static void main(String[] args) throws SolrServerException,
IOException {
String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/huda";
SolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();

SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("*:*");  
SolrRequest<QueryResponse> req = new QueryRequest(query);
QueryResponse rsp = req.process(solr);

System.out.println("numFound: " + rsp.getResults().getNumFound());

TermsResponse termResp =rsp.getTermsResponse();
List<Term> terms = termResp.getTerms("name");
System.out.print(terms.size());
        }
```

I got this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at solr_test.solr.App2.main(App2.java:50)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should change a bit your code in order to get the `terms` statistics in your solr query response.

Try out something like this:

```
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setTerms(true);
    query.addTermsField("name");
    SolrRequest<QueryResponse> req = new QueryRequest(query);
    QueryResponse rsp = req.process(solr);

    TermsResponse termResp = rsp.getTermsResponse();
    List<TermsResponse.Term> terms = termResp.getTerms("name");
```

*NOTE* that the `setQuery` method is not used in the provided code. Internally, because of this, the solr request will be directed to the *Terms* handler and not to the *Query* handler.

[Solr Terms Component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Terms+Component)

Comment: what do you mean?? I tried this but it didn't work:

    `SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();`
`query.setQuery("*:*");`

`query.setTerms(true);`
`query.addTermsField("name");`
`query.addTermsField("id");`

`SolrRequest<QueryResponse> req = new QueryRequest(query);`
`QueryResponse rsp = req.process(solr);`


`TermsResponse termResp =rsp.getTermsResponse();`
`List<Term> terms = termResp.getTerms("name");`
`System.out.print(terms.size());`

Comment: sorry, i should have added the whole snippet of code and not only the first few lines of it. I've done that in the meantime. You don't need to call `setQuery(String)` method in the example from comment in order to get the terms.

Comment: I tried that but I got :
      `numFound: 0`
     
and I got this error:
      
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at solr_test.solr.App3.main(App3.java:44)`

Comment: see this [sample code](http://pastebin.com/ppJ7WU54) with the _techproducts_ example collection that comes with the solr installation.

Comment: I tried that its exactly the same as my code and I get the same exception that I mentioned in my question.
The problem is in the query as it gives numFound=0 I don't know why??